# Convert Decimal to Hexadecimal in R

Tags: r

How do I convert large decimal values to Hexadecimal in R?

I'm aware of the as.hexmode(x) function, but it seems to have a size limitation.

An example of a number I want to convert : 6917530144339624323

Comment: Why do you need to support such large hex values?

Comment: Need to convert user IDs which are coded differently on different platforms

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [gmp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/gmp.pdf) library

```
library(gmp)
x <- '6917530144339624323'
x_bigz <- as.bigz(x)
as.character(x_bigz, b = 16)
[1] "60000104006b8183"
```